# sum field values based on condition in another field in javascript

Tags: javascript, foxit

I am attempting to sum a number of field values but only if a condition associated with those filed values is met.  For example:

I have a form with several number value fields.  Each of those number fields is accompanied by a choice in status.  I simply want to add all of the number fields of the same status, or possibly some with a couple different status.  Here is the code I tried, that does not work:

```
// field names
var cTotal1 = "Day1Pd1Total";
var cTotal2 = "Day1Pd2Total";
var cTotal3 = "Day1Pd3Total";
var cTotal4 = "Day1Pd4Total";
var cTotal5 = "Day1Pd5Total";
var cTotal6 = "Day1Pd6Total";
var cStatus1 = "Day1Pd1Status";
var cStatus2 = "Day1Pd2Status";
var cStatus3 = "Day1Pd3Status";
var cStatus4 = "Day1Pd4Status";
var cStatus5 = "Day1Pd5Status";
var cStatus6 = "Day1Pd6Status";
// get conditonal field values
var vStatus1 = this.getField(cStatus1).value;
var vStatus2 = this.getField(cStatus2).value;
var vStatus3 = this.getField(cStatus3).value;
var vStatus4 = this.getField(cStatus4).value;
var vStatus5 = this.getField(cStatus5).value;
var vStatus6 = this.getField(cStatus6).value;
// get field values base on condition
if(vStatus1 = "1"){
var vTotal1 = this.getField(cTotal1).value;
}else{
var vTotal1 = "0"; 
}
if(vStatus2 = "1"){
var vTotal2 = this.getField(cTotal2).value;
}else{
var vTotal2 = "0";
}
if(vStatus3 = "1"){
var vTotal3 = this.getField(cTotal3).value;
}else{
var vTotal3 = "0"; 
}
if(vStatus4 = "1"){
var vTotal4 = this.getField(cTotal4).value;
}else{
vTotal4 = "0";
}
if(vStatus5 = "1"){
var vTotal5 = this.getField(cTotal5).value;
}else{
vTotal5 = "0";
}
if(vStatus6 = "1"){
var vTotal6 = this.getField(cTotal6).value;
}else{
vTotal6 = "0";
}
// clear result value
event.value = "";
// add values
var FLPTotal = vTotal1+ vTotal2 + vTotal3 + vTotal4 + vTotal5 + vTotal6;
event.value = FLPTotal;
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
var FLPTotal = vTotal1(vStatus1 == "1") + vTotal2(vStatus2 == "1") +vTotal3(vStatus3 == "1") +vTotal4(vStatus4 == "1") +vTotal5(vStatus5 == "1") +vTotal6(vStatus6 == "1")
```

My knowledge of JavaScript is fairly poor, I admit.  Any help would be genuinely appreciated.  Thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

After working on this some more, I noticed it was riddled with syntax errors.  After fixing them, I got this to work:

```
// field names
var cTotal1 = "Day1Pd1Total";
var cTotal2 = "Day1Pd2Total";
var cTotal3 = "Day1Pd3Total";
var cTotal4 = "Day1Pd4Total";
var cTotal5 = "Day1Pd5Total";
var cTotal6 = "Day1Pd6Total";
var cStatus1 = "Day1Pd1Status";
var cStatus2 = "Day1Pd2Status";
var cStatus3 = "Day1Pd3Status";
var cStatus4 = "Day1Pd4Status";
var cStatus5 = "Day1Pd5Status";
var cStatus6 = "Day1Pd6Status";
// get conditonal field values
var vStatus1 = this.getField(cStatus1).value;
var vStatus2 = this.getField(cStatus2).value;
var vStatus3 = this.getField(cStatus3).value;
var vStatus4 = this.getField(cStatus4).value;
var vStatus5 = this.getField(cStatus5).value;
var vStatus6 = this.getField(cStatus6).value;
// get field values base on condition
if(vStatus1 == "1"){
var vTotal1 = this.getField(cTotal1).value;
}else{
var vTotal1 = "";
}
if(vStatus2 == "1"){
var vTotal2 = this.getField(cTotal2).value;
}else{
var vTotal2 = "";
}
if(vStatus3 == "1"){
var vTotal3 = this.getField(cTotal3).value;
}else{
var vTotal3 = "";
}
if(vStatus4 == "1"){
var vTotal4 = this.getField(cTotal4).value;
}else{
var vTotal4 = "";
}
if(vStatus5 == "1"){
var vTotal5 = this.getField(cTotal5).value;
}else{
var vTotal5 = "";
}
if(vStatus6 == "1"){
var vTotal6 = this.getField(cTotal6).value;
}else{
var vTotal6 = "";
}
// clear result value
event.value = "";
// add values
var FLPTotal = vTotal1 + vTotal2 + vTotal3 + vTotal4 + vTotal5 + vTotal6;
event.value = FLPTotal;
```

I am not sure it is as streamlined as it could be, but it is doing what I need.